# modal not showing up even if i set it to visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to create a popup window when I click button "register" and "download". I put the class trigger into those button as a class and added a click listener to that class. However when I go and try to click the button to toggle the "show-modal" class to it, it doesn't show. I inspected the website and I can see the button works and the class is actually added to it when I click the button but nothing is showing? So I tried to set the visibility to visible but still nothing is showing. I'm not sure what to do. If someone good guide me to find the answer that would be great. I'm still trying to learn how to use my resources more effectively!

modal code (works/shows) ----> https://jsfiddle.net/51xr6y78/17/

modal code imbedded into my website (won't show) ----> https://jsfiddle.net/hq6vp4ee/

HTML

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-button">&times;</div>
        <h1>This is my modal.</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main-page-btn container">
        <a href="#" class="register trigger">Register</a>
        <a href="#" class="download trigger">Download</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
   transform: scale(1.1);
   transition: visibility 0s, linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}

.show-modal{
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
   transform: scale(1.0);
   transition: visibility 0s, linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

JS

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal(){
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event){
    if (event.target === modal){
        toggleModal();
    }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

Comment: You need to give **brackets** to your functions referenced inside `addEventListener` (like `toggleModal()`)... though your modal shows as open by default for me.

Comment: There's a lot going on here. For starters the jsfiddle you linked to does not match up with the code posted here, so depending on which one people read, you may get different answers. The simplest way to hide or show the modal would be to simply set `display: none` in `.modal` and `display: block` in `.show-modal`, but it looks like you are also trying to do some transitions that will require a bit more work. Currently both your default `.modal` and `.show-modal` styles include css that would make it visible, so I would expect it to always display, not never display.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed that now. However the main problem i'm having is that I can't get it to show up at all. I feel like it might be hidden behind something but I'm not sure...

Comment: @ChrisBoon okay I will update the jsfiddle

Comment: so I just tried it with that code, changed the visibility back to hidden and it works. So i'm guessing that it's maybe hidden behind the other stuff on my website?

Comment: @ObsidianAge - you don't add 'brackets' in event listeners - that would trigger the function on page load. eg - `trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);` correctly binds the function to the event, whereas `trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal());` causes the function to trigger on page load.

Comment: @ChrisBoon -- Correct; my bad. I'm so used to writing out functions manually inside listeners haha. It's been a long day ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that `.modal` class is probably defined before(ie, Bootstrap).

Just change the `.modal` class name :

```css
.myModal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

And your html: `<div class="myModal">`

And in your js `var modal = document.querySelector(".myModal");`

cheers

Answer (score 0):

A problem you are having here is actually with your events triggering.
If we look at your JS as posted above:

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal(){
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event){
    if (event.target === modal){
        toggleModal();
    }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

You are trying to add the click event two ways - directly on the button, and delegated via the window. The direct version is working correctly:

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");

function toggleModal(){
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}


trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
```

You have correctly added an eventlistener to the button and clicking it calls the 'toggleModal' event.

However the event on the window is a problem:

```
function windowOnClick(event){
    if (event.target === modal){
        toggleModal();
    }
}
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

If you add a console.log in that function like this:

```
function windowOnClick(event){
  console.log(event.target)
  if (event.target === modal){
    toggleModal();
  }
}
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

You will see that the `event.target` is equal to `<a href="#" class="register trigger">Register</a>`, not `modal`. There are ways you coud fix this, but it's not necessary as your direct method would work if you just remove this one.

The second issue I see is, as you suggested, your modal is appearing behind other content so you never see it. If you add `z-index:2` to `.show-modal` it should move it in front of your content.